# Probability question about convolution

Tags: probability, convolution, uniform-distribution

I'm preparing for Probability Theory and Mathematical Statistics exam and I've got some struggles with one exercise.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/exams/MIT6_041F10_quiz02_s08_sol.pdf

I'm analyzing Question 1 c)
[image]

I just don't understand where did bounders $[3.5,4]$ come from:

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f_Y(4.5-\alpha)$ only has support on $\alpha \in [3.5, 4.5]$ and $f_X(\alpha)$ only has support on $\alpha \in [0, 4]$ so their product only has support on $\alpha \in [3.5,4]$. Try plotting the functions to see this better.